# How to remove y-ticklabels, y-label and x-label from seaborn

Tags: seaborn

When plotting a count plot in seaborn with the code : g=sns.countplot(x='Vertical', data=Report), am getting x-label as "Vertical" and y-label as "count" and values along y-axis. How to remove x-label, y-label and y-values?

Comment: Add these lines `ax=sns.countplot(x='Vertical', data=Report); ax.set_ylabel(None); ax.set_xlabel(None); ax.set_yticks([])`